# Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Event'

Tags: jquery, events, typescript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to get the selected value from the click-event using `select2` and `TypeScript (2.1)`. I followed the example [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#events):

However, in `TypeScript` I always get the following error:

> Symbol 'params' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module

when trying to access `evt.params`.

My function:

```
// bind to the select-event
$theElement.on("select2:select", (evt: Event) => {
    if (!evt) {
        var args = "{}";
    } else {
        var args = JSON.stringify(evt.params, function (key, value) { // <-- here is the error
            if (value && value.nodeName) return "[DOM node]";
            if (value instanceof $.Event) return "[$.Event]";
            return value;
        });
    }
});
```

I checked the `Event`'s source a.k.a. lib.d.ts located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.1` and indeed, there is no `params` defined.

So, how can I access the property without changing the type to `any`?

Here is a screenshot from Chrome's `Developer Tools`:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `evt` will have a `params` property at runtime? I don't see it mentioned in the select2 documentation.

Comment: @Saravana Added a screenshot from developer tools. So - yes, at runtime there is the property.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most elegant solution, but You can access this property with `event['params']`.

I'm not sure if the idea of casting You suggested, but doing it just for this one call, isn't better though: `(event as any).params`.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `Event` type refers to a [standard DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), whereas your function's parameter looks like it may be a jQuery event customized by the select2 library. Assuming `params` is indeed a property specific to the select2 library (which I don't see in the documentation), you'd need to [reference a type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-i-get-them) specific to [select2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/select2) in your TypeScript file.

If you can't find a type definition with the `params` property, you can make your own by creating an interface that extends either `JQueryEventObject` from jQuery's type definition or `Select2JQueryEventObject` from select2's.

Comment: I checked the typings for `select2` which I have in use. The also do not have `params` defined...

Comment: Well then it is probably an issue with the typings or `params` is an undocumented property.